# Set dynamic Value for Modal Action Form

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I need to set dynamic value for Modal popup.

This is my modal

```
 <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="popUpModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">"this is the value {{ cra }}"</h4>
        </div>
        <form class="modal-form" id="docsForm" action="{% url 'contact_delete' pk=contact.id %}"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="upload" />
<input type="hidden" name="brandcode" value=this.id />
<input type="submit" /></form>
        <div class="modal-footer">

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

This is what I am trying

```
<script>
    $('#popUpModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

      var $modal = $(this),
        esseyId = e.relatedTarget.id;
        $modal.find('.modal-form').html(esseyId);

    })
  </script>
```

based on the record I want value like

```
contact/delete/1
contact/delete/2
....
```

**Update 1**

```
          <a id="{{ contact.id }}" type="button" data-target="#popUpModal" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="{% trans 'Update Doc' %}">
```

Comment: I think you want to change the action url based on the modal popup ?

Comment: @RajaSimon yes this is what I need

Comment: Okay. Then you have to explain bit more about. What button user presses to open the modal. Then will figure out the way to update the url..

Comment: Well there is a upload button for each row, based on which modal gets called. Updated the code as well

Comment: In the last line of your javascript did you get your modal ?

Comment: yes, I am getting the value, but facing issues while updating the url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145343/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-onkar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way I am getting the expected response

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#popUpModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var id= button.data('id') // Extract info from data-* attributes

  var modal = $(this)
  console.log(id)
  $("#docsForm").attr("action", "/contact_delete/" + id+"/");
})
 </script>
```